# mySQL float column set as default 0 sometimes contains wierd value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin 4.0.10.7 on my server and I have a float column that sometimes doesn't work as itended: it is set as default: 0, but sometimes the value is entered as 0.00000000953674 when a new row is added.
Why is this happening?

Comment: That FLOAT is working as intended. You probably want DECIMAL.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are not stored as exact values. See MySQL's writeup on the issue [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html).

Unless you have a specific need for floating point precision, I would recommend switching to the `DECIMAL` type, which does not have this problem (as of MySQL 5.0.3). If you must use floats, just remember that the values will not be exact, and direct comparisons will not always work (i.e. `WHERE myVal = 5`). Instead you should do ranged comparisons (i.e. `WHERE myVal > 4.999 AND myVal < 5.001`).